# How to login into the web application using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

How to login into the web application using JMeter and what are the parameters we need to give for login, logout and login button?

Answer (score 4):

#### How do I login into a web application using JMeter?

This is documented in the [User Manual](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/#index).

The instructions below are for login, logout will be similar.

---

#### Logging in to a web-site

> It's not the case here, but some web-sites require you to login
> before permitting you to perform certain actions. In a web-browser,
> the login will be shown as a form for the user name and password, and
> a button to submit the form. The button generates a POST request,
> passing the values of the form items as parameters.
>
> To do this in JMeter, add an HTTP Request, and set the method to POST.
> You'll need to know the names of the fields used by the form, and the
> target page. These can be found out by inspecting the code of the
> login page. [If this is difficult to do, you can use the [JMeter Proxy
> Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Proxy_Server) to record the login sequence.] Set the path to the target
> of the submit button. Click the Add button twice and enter the
> username and password details. Sometimes the login form contains
> additional hidden fields. These will need to be added as well.

[image]

Source [5.6 Logging in to a web-site](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html)

Answer (score 0):

The usual scenario looks as follows:

1. Record login/logout flow using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. Parametrize scenario for multi-user testing to provide different credentials for each virtual user with i.e. [CSV Data Set config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
3. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to enable cookies support
4. Detect all dynamic parameters which are hard-coded during recording and substitute them with variables. See [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) guide for example on how to implement it.